# Lowest Common Multiple with doubles in C

Tags: c, double, lcm

I am doing an assignment for a Coursera class that asks me to calculate the Lowest Common Multiple of two numbers, either of which are no larger than 2 * 10 ^ 9.  I'm writing this in C and I'm running my code on a test case with the numbers 226553150 and 1023473145. The answer is 46374212988031350, but I'm getting 46374212988031344, which is off by 6!

I've written a correct solution in Python that uses essentially the same approach as the one I've posted below, but the details of numeric precision are obviously taken care of for me.  I post this to SO to learn something about floating point precision in C, and because most of the questions I've seen on the internet and SO regarding LCM deal only with integers.

Here is my code, which I'm compiling with `gcc -pipe -O2 -std=c11 lcm.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double gcd(double a, double b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }

    return gcd(b, fmod(a,b));
}

double lcm(double a, double b) {
    return (a * b) / gcd(a,b);
}

int main() {

    double a;
    double b;

    scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b);

    printf("%.0lf\n", lcm(a,b));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use float point calculations in such tasks. Use only integers. Use long long if you need high precision (or arbitrary-precision arithmetic if long long is not big enough)

Comment: This formula `(a * b) / gcd(a,b)` will result in more digits than `double` can hold. Think how to improve the formula so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: double has only ~15 digits of precision. It can't store 46374212988031350 precisely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest number to `46374212988031350` that can be represented by a `double` is `46374212988031352` (off by `2`). You can test that by using the most straight forward calculation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   // The gcd of 226553150 and 1023473145 is 5
   double a = 226553150;
   double b = 1023473145;
   double c = b/5;

   double lcm = a*c;

   printf("lcm: %.0lf\n", lcm);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
lcm: 46374212988031352
```

You are making things worse by computing `(a * b)/gcd(a, b)`. The closest number to `231871064940156750`, `(a*b)`, that can be represented by floating point numbers is `231871064940156736`. In other words, you are losing more accuracy by computing `(a*b)` first.

You haven't posted the Python code you used to do the same computation. I am guessing Python is using integral types for the numbers. If I use:

```python
a = 226553150;
b = 1023473145;
c = b/5;

lcm = a*c

print("lcm:", lcm)
```

I get the output:

```
('lcm:', 46374212988031350)
```

However, if I use floating point literals for `a` and `b`, I get a different output:

```
a = 226553150.0;
b = 1023473145.0;
c = b/5;

lcm = a*c

print("lcm:", "%18.0lf" % lcm)
```

Output:

```
('lcm:', ' 46374212988031352')
```

In summary, the difference you are seeing between the C program and the Python program is due to use of floating point types vs integral types. If you use `long` or `long long` instead of `double`, you should get the same output as the Python program, as shown in [the answer by Deng Haijun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36540404/434551).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt why you use float not long. I change float to long as following, then it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long gcd(long a, long b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }

    return gcd(b, a%b);
}

long lcm(long a, long b) {
    return (a * b) / gcd(a,b);
}

int main() {

    long a;
    long b;

    scanf("%ld %ld", &a, &b);
    printf("%ld\n", lcm(a,b));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: long is 32 bit even on 64-bit Windows. The recommended way is `int64_t`