# Python calculation error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement an LCM finding algorithm. It needs to find LCM for very large numbers.

LCM is found using the formula,

```
LCM(A, B) = (A * B) / GCD(A, B)
```

where A and B are two inputs.

Input: `226553150 1023473145`
So, `LCM = (226553150 * 1023473145) / 5`
It should be, `46374212988031350`.

But python is finding this as `46374212988031352`, which is obviously an error. 
How to solve this problem ?
[image: python screenshot]

Comment: Floating point math is **not precise**.

Comment: You can read more about the limits of floating points here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Looks like this is a Coursera course, I see there's a [C question on the same subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540103/lowest-common-multiple-with-doubles-in-c).

Answer (score 4):

You are using floating point math, because you used the `/` true division operator. Floating point can only approximate large numbers, and the difference you see is a result of that.

Use `//` floor division instead:

```
>>> (226553150 * 1023473145) // 5
46374212988031350
```

Floor division on integers never requires conversion to float, avoiding the precision issues.

Alternatively, use the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for higher-precision math with real numbers:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('226553150') * Decimal('1023473145') / Decimal('5')
Decimal('46374212988031350')
```

This is slower than using `float`.